# PHPMyAdmin downloads the index file instead of opening it in the webpage

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

So i just downloaded phpmyadmin through apt. When i tried to open it in my webbrowser it downloaded the index file instead of executing it. Ive been googling for like 2h now and every answer i find is you dont have php enabled. The thing is, i do. I am running a different PHP site and that one works fine. Any help would be appreciated!

- PHP version 7.4
- Apache version 2.4.29
- PHPMyAdmin apache conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
   Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   DirectoryIndex index.php

   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
       <IfModule mod_mime.c>
           AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
       </IfModule>
       <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
           SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
       </FilesMatch>

       php_value include_path .
       php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
       php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
       php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_php.c>
       <IfModule mod_mime.c>
           AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
       </IfModule>
       <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
           SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
       </FilesMatch>

       php_value include_path .
       php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
       php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
       php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
   </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
       <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
           AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
       </IfModule>
       Require valid-user
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
   Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
   Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

If you need any more information, just ask and ill add it.

**EDIT:**
The issue still occurs when apache is disabled

Comment: Welcome, is `mod_mime` installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: I realize now that your configuration says `IfModule mod_php5` but your php version is 7.4...

Comment: Did you copy and paste the configuration from some site?

Comment: Yeah i did. Guess thats what messed it up. Ill give it a shot now

Comment: Gave it a shot, its still downloading that file...

Comment: My phpadmin (php 7.4) configuration file is very simple [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hJXs2xVVwH/)

Comment: Remember to restar apache after any changes.

Comment: I use `phpmyadmin.local` as nameserver, added at `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I've got another bit of information. Even when I stop apache entirely it still downloads..... So the problem lies elsewhere but idk where

Comment: @Crack3dC0d3 nuke your browser cache.  And see if the issue persists.  (Browsers are notorious at caching).  If Apache is stopped and it doesn't work anymore then you know your browser's cache was at fault.

Comment: Thank you, That fixed the issue